# loop through class members with a referenced array (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, reference, member

I'd like to loop through a set of members which are of the same type. Here is a solution which sometimes works, sometimes not:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class Test{
   public:
      Test():xmin(0),ymin(0),xmax(0),ymax(0),acs((vector<int> (&)[4])xmin){};
      vector<int> xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax;
      vector<int> (&acs)[4];
};
int main(){
   Test t;
   t.xmin.push_back(2);
   cout << t.xmin.size() << "=!=" <<t.acs[0].size() << endl;
}
```

the above test code works for me. In a much bigger program I do at the moment it does not, i.e. t.ymin does not seems to be the same as t.acs[1] and so on.
Is the above construct in general meaningful or should I do it completely different?

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: You're certainly playing with undefined behaviour there. There's no guarantee that consecutive class members are laid out in the same way as array elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array of pointers to members. This way is probably fastest (seems like it's important to you), but a bit obscure, and you have to mention the list of your member variables a second time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Test
{
    std::vector<int> xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax;

    std::vector<int>& GetByIndex(int index)
    {
        typedef std::vector<int> Test::*ptr_to_member; // typedef makes syntax less crazy

        static const ptr_to_member pointers[4] = {
            &Test::xmin, &Test::ymin, &Test::xmax, &Test::ymax
        };

        return this->*pointers[index];
    }
};

int main(){
    Test t;
    t.xmin.push_back(2);
    std::cout << t.xmin.size() << "=!=" << t.GetByIndex(0).size() << '\n';
}
```

If you don't need speed, a very simple solution involves a switch:

```
std::vector<int>& GetByIndex(int index)
{
    switch (index) {
    case 0: return xmin;
    case 1: return ymin;
    case 2: return xmax;
    case 3: return ymax;
    default: abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: `abort`ing on a wrong index :) that's nice... The switch version although "slower" shouldn't really be noticeable.

Comment: Thanks, that will do the trick! On a related issue: I modified your approach by setting the pointers in the constructor `Test():xmin(0),ymin(0),xmax(0),ymax(0),acs({&xmin,&ymin,&xmax,&ymax}){};` and the member `vector<int>* acs[4];` . That seems to work in the test script but i now get a warning `warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x` . The same warning occurs if I assign in the contructor and not in the initializer list. Should I bother? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mike Seymour -absolutely right - your solution is dangerous.

Try inject following:

```
class Test
{
    struct AllArrays
    {
        vector<int> * vec1, .... * vecN;
    };
    union 
    { 
        AllArrays _as_fields;
        vector<int> * _as_Array[];
    } _allTogether;
};
```

The payload for this that you need write little bit long qualifier:

```
Test t;
t._allTogether._as_fields.vec1
```

Comment: `union` containing `vector` is invalid (doesn't compile), at least in C++03

Comment: @anatolyg take a look that I have used pointer `vector<int> *`. Pointers are allowed inside union!

Comment: Then, you must use `vector<int>* as_array[4]` instead of `vector<int> [] _as_Array`

Comment: Thanks, but indeed the qualifier gets quit long (-;

Answer (score 0):

This is very bad practice. In particular, you're dependend on [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) details. There's no guarantee that the compiler will layout the data members without any padding in between. If you *mean* array, *use* an array. My 2c...